# .desktop file for AppImage gets icon in Activities but not in Launcher

Tags: 22.04, .desktop, desktop-icons, arduino, appimage

I'm running the Arduino IDE appimage on Ubuntu.

`arduino-ide_2.1.1_Linux_64bit.AppImage` on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

I've 'installed' the appimage file in `~/.arduinoIDE/`

I've made a .desktop file that looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Arduino IDE
Comment=Adruino IDE
Exec=/home/<user>/.arduinoIDE/arduino-ide_2.1.1_Linux_64bit.AppImage
Icon=/home/<user>/.arduinoIDE/arduino-icon-transparent-32x32.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Programming;
Keywords=Arduino;IDE;Programming;
```

The .desktop file seems to work, at least partly. The application is searchable from the Activities view (the search bar that appears when you press the 'super' key), it appears with the right icon and the program can be launched successfully and runs ok.

However, once running the icon that shows up in the launcher bar is some kind of default missing icon icon, not the one linked in the .desktop file. What do I need to do to fix this?

Also, the .desktop file includes the Categories=Programming; info however, when I right click a file and select choose 'open with...' the Arduino IDE is not present under the Programming category.

Finally, in the launcher the 'add to favourites' option is not there. Is there a way to get this to show up?